# Configure U-Boot with Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot, yocto

I'm using Yocto to build an embedded environment. I want to change the actual recipe of generation of bootloader. Exist a graphical tool to edit the u-boot recipe? Or how can I change the packages available in u-boot image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of board are you using?
From the NXP forum, I have found a document on modifying the U-boot for Freescale i.MX6X.  It contains information about U-boot Set Up, Image Install Instruction, How to use U-boot, etc.
The link is [here](https://community.freescale.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/320516-257543/uboot_mx6x.pdf)

To find the u-boot and modify, you need to look at the machine configuration.  In there, it will shows where the kernel and u-boot comes from.
For example, [the iMX6 sabrelite](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm-extra/blob/master/conf/machine/imx6qsabrelite.conf)

Then, find the bsp for [u-boot recipe](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm-extra/blob/master/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-boundary_git.bb) for the compatible machine 
In there, at URI, you will find the git repository that tell [where the u-boot is](https://github.com/boundarydevices/u-boot-imx6/tree/boundary-v2015.07), change the branch and clone the u-boot.

Then, do whatever you want to modify the u-boot. After that, point your machine u-boot URI to where you store the u-boot repository.

Comment: Charles C. 
Do you have another place that is posted? When I click on it there is a un-secure connection page that pops up.

Comment: I uploaded to google drive here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Amp7kr6ZeJu7Gn90O-wvrhOJ6T7Cv8N

Comment: Old, old way of doing things- and clumsy/easily oopsed.  See the other answer for what you wanted to do since well before Kirkstone if you want a good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

While this is ***old***, there's probably someone looking for this answer (Along with the ability to do other menuconfig configurations in Yocto transparently...) as it is a common refrain.  Got this lovely config-frag system for Yocto to frame in subsets of configuration for a Menuconfig build system and NO tooling to easily MAKE these things.

Well, look no further than some of the .bbclass-es from PHA-Linux.  There's a means unto which you can have Yocto generate .cfg configuration fragments for Yocto's build processes fairly transparently.

First, you either need to be using meta-pha (My distro's metadata layer) or crib pieces from it.

[meta-pha from Github](https://github.com/madscientist42/meta-pha)

You'll want the following FROM this:

pha-menuconfig.bbclass
process_frag.awk

These two will empower you, via a .bbappend to do this very thing.

All you need to do to activate the menuconfig frag generator tool is inherit pha-menuconfig (Or whatever you call it...)  in the beginnings of your .bbappend or .bb file and add the following minimum definition in your file just before the inherit:

LOCAL_FILES_PATH := "${THISDIR}/${PN}"

The inherit will prepend the value assigned to ${LOCAL_FILES_PATH} to FILESEXTRAPATHS properly and then stage it up for the generator to do it's right things.  (It was designed this way to force it to the recipe you're extending this to since there's no good way to sanely drop the configuration fragment into otherwise...)  From there, just call, "-c menuconfig" on the recipes you've extended with this and just do what you'd normally do.  It will on exit of the menuconfig session for the recipe drop a config_frag.cfg file in the path specified by LOCAL_FILES_PATH.  You can then fairly easily rename the fragment to what you want/need with the .cfg extension and add it to your SRC_URI path.